# Dell D630 pink tint on screen when powering on, what will happen?

Tags: windows-xp, display, dell-latitude

I've been given a Dell D630 laptop by a friend. I got it in the mail yesterday and it was quite cold, I plugged the power in and after 20 mins I switched it on.

The contents of the screen had a pink tint, moreso on the left side of the screen.

I've read around on the net and found that there was a fault with nvidia coolers, I've done their bios update and since, I get a pink tint for a short time which goes away.

I'm just wondering if it will get any worse.

Is it likely that the screen will fail ?

How long do you think the screen will last ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the screen, it is a faulty Nvidia chip, they did not design the cooling of the chip properly and the chip overheats and eventually destroys itself, some have done their own customizing on the cooling by adding copper shims between the nvidia chip and the heat sink, not for the novice to do this type of repair.
http://forum.notebookreview.com/dell-latitude-vostro-precision/434935-latitude-d630-nvs-135m-copper-mod.html

See this

http://www.nvidiasettlement.com/affectedmodels.html

Comment: So will this happen to all Dell Latitude D630 in time ?

Comment: How can I tell what temperature the chip is ?

Comment: Did you go to the nvidia settlement site I posted? Your model is listed, Yes it is one that will go bad.

Answer (score 0):

The pink tint is caused by a failing backlight, not the Nvidia GPU.

The screen will continue to operate for a random amount of time, but will fail in time when the backlight goes completely, its quite possible the inverter will also burn itself out if you continue to use the screen.

Either get the screen repaired (new backlight) or replace the screen, or buy a new laptop.